# Subquery returned more than 1 value error on an inner join

Tags: sql-server

Getting the old

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

error when I try to run this script:

```
SELECT  name_first,
        name_last
FROM person
INNER JOIN message
    ON person.person_id = (
        SELECT message.recipient_id 
        FROM message 
        WHERE message.filename = '1003-5ivGbUqIz80r0NwCl9kzWpDjYDit9L.mp3')
```

Any help with figuring out what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have a subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name_first, name_last
FROM   person 
       INNER JOIN message 
         ON person.person_id = message.recipient_id  
WHERE  message.filename = '1003-5ivGbUqIz80r0NwCl9kzWpDjYDit9L.mp3'
```

`DISTINCT` was specified on the `SELECT` clause to display only unique name of person assuming that it can have multiple messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this type of sub query insted of Joins......

USE [FydaDB]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CountryManagerReport]    Script Date: 5/25/2018 2:12:42 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountryManagerReport] 
        @FromDate datetime,
        @Todate datetime,
        @countryId int
    AS
    BEGIN
    Select FirstName+ ' ' + MiddleName+ '' +  LastName as FullName ,Email,CNIC,((select CountryCode from Country where ID=FydaAdmin.CountryId)+ '-' +(select PhoneNo from Contacts where FydaAdminId=FydaAdmin.ID)) as Mobile,
    (ZipCode+ ' ,' +[Address]+ ' ,' + (select Name from City where ID=FydaAdmin.CityId )+ ', ' +(select Name from States where ID=FydaAdmin.StateId )+ ', ' +(select Name from Country where ID=FydaAdmin.CountryId)
     ) as [Address]
     from FydaAdmin where CreatedDateTime  BETWEEN  @FromDate  and @Todate or CountryId=@countryId 
    END
```